# Handling chunk files in large Angular 4 applications

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm working in a large Angular 4 application and we're facing some issue with the required setup we have.

Basically, the root application contains a simple login and a simple home screen. From here, the user can navigate to other sub-applications which are a lazily loaded chunk files that will be injected in a router-outlet in the root application. So far everything is working if all of these files were in the same repository and available in build time, but they're not.

The sub-applications is located in a total different repository and we cannot rebuild the root application when sub-applications gets updated. So all sub-application build their own production ready JS's and deploy it to the web server.

Today we're using SystemJS since it's was the only bundler (back in the days when we started this project) that had the ability to set the name of the chunk files for our sub-applications. But today it's possible to eject webpack from Angular-CLI and we see big advantages to move to webpack to be able to use features like ahead of time compilation for example.

Anyone have this kind of setup or any idea how to configure webpack both for root application as well as sub-applications?